# DrawArc works correct for circle but invalid for ellipse

Tags: c#, graphics

I am drawing using System.Drawing.Graphics class.
I need my application to draw arcs for both circles and ellipses.

Here is a code example

```
            graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100), 135, 270);
            graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(100, 210, 100, 75), 135, 270);
            graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(100, 290, 100, 50), 135, 270);
            graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(100, 350, 100, 25), 135, 270);
```

Image below shows the result.

[image]

I just cannot understand why the gap between the two points is reducing? I expect it to remain the same?

Comment: Mark the center of the ellipses and draw the straight lines from there to the two end points and you will see that the angle is always he same. Simple geometry.

Comment: @KlausGütter: vertical lines are already there at the picture - please take a closer look and you will see that angles are not the same

Comment: @KlausGütter: thank you. Now I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here - all right angles:
[image: Ellipses]

You may get a better idea of what's happening if you consider the limit case of vanishing height.